# Android Studio cannot start aapt on Kali Linux

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt

I installed Kali Linux on my PC yesterday and installed Android Studio. But when I build a project Android Studio gives me these errors:

> Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''

I searched little on the internet. There is a solution for that:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

When I run these commands in the terminal, it says:

```
Lîsteya pakêtan tê xwendin... Çêbû //reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree                
Reading state information... Çêbû
E: Pakêt nehate dîtin lib32stdc++6 //package is not found... Done
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32stdc++6'
```

What can I do?

Comment: When you run `aapt` by yourself, from the command line, what errors do you get?

Comment: It is not playing/running. So I don't get any error..

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is arising due to the misconfiguration of android adb and android development tools. 
You Need to install some extra  packages from the market place.
 ***Android SDK Build-tools
(1)Location: $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/$VERSION/***
(2)[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html)

> 3.)Main tools: aapt (to generate R.java and unaligned, unsigned APKs), dx (to convert Java bytecode to Dalvik bytecode), and zipalign (to optimize your APKs).